# Oracle display value replacement of flattened, delimited foreign key values

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, csv

I working on a data export for a painfully denormalized COTS product and am hung up over how to plug display values in my selection for columns that contain a delimited string of foreign keys.

Assume the following sets of data for example.

**DEPARTMENTS** table:

```
Key   Value
---------------------------------
1     Finance
2     Human Resources
3     Public Affairs
4     Information Technology
```

**PERSONNEL** table:

```
PK    FName    LName    Departments
-------------------------------------------------
111   Marty    Graw     1|~*~|3|~*~|
222   Rick     Shaw     2|~*~|4|~*~|
333   Jean     Poole    4|~*~|2|~*~|3|~*~|1|~*~|
```

Desired output from select:

```
FName    LName    Departments
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Marty    Graw     Finance, Public Affairs
Rick     Shaw     Human Resources, Information Technology
Jean     Poole    Information Technology, Human Resources, Public Affairs, Finance
```

I've found examples of how to deal with delimited strings but nothing that really seems to fit this particular scenario. Ideally I'd like to figure out how I could do it without having to create functions etc. as my permissions are pretty limited.

Comment: Does it matter if the department names might be listed in a different order than that with which the IDs are listed in the Departments column?

Comment: This is a **horrible** way to store foreign keys. You really shouldn't be doing that. Why don't you properly normalize your data model and then this query becomes a dead simple join.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I couldn't agree more! Unfortunately this is a vendor (COTS) application that has a poorly designed database. They are relying on the application for pretty much all of their data integrity. There isn't a single foreign key constraint in the entire database! It's just ridiculous!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, it's not helpful to chastise the OP for poor designs when they have already acknowledged the problem in their very first sentence, and stated they are not responsible for the poor design. In the real world. we have to deal with suboptimal designs all the time, and sometimes "redesign from scratch" is not the best option for the customer.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp: I disagree. Keeping a design like that is almost always the worst choice. As I have no idea what a COTS product is (never heard of that company), I couldn't know that this wasn't a homegrown solution.

Comment: It means Commercial Off The Shelf. In other words, you can't change it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Jeffery is correct COTS (Commercial Off The Shelf) basically means that the business team bought a vendor solution instead of building it in-house. Now that it is implemented, we are stuck supporting it. If you've never been in that situation, it almost always sucks because vendor solutions are rarely a perfect fit and depending on the quality of bag your left holding,adding customizations etc. can be very painful. A database of my own design would **NEVER** be like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not preserve the original order of the IDs, but if that's not important then this will work:

```
select DISTINCT
       p.fname
      ,p.name
      ,LISTAGG(d.value, ', ')
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY d.value)
       OVER (PARTITION BY p.pk)
       AS departments_list
from personnel p
left join departments d
on INSTR('|~*~|'||p.departments||'|~*~|'
        ,'|~*~|'||d.key||'|~*~|') > 0;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d292e/3/0

**EDIT**

If you really need them listed in the same order as the IDs, you can use this variant:

```
select DISTINCT
       p.fname
      ,p.lname
      ,LISTAGG(d.value, ', ')
       WITHIN GROUP (
         ORDER BY INSTR('|~*~|'||p.departments||'|~*~|'
                       ,'|~*~|'||d.key||'|~*~|'))
       OVER (PARTITION BY p.pk) AS departments_list
from personnel p
left join departments d
on INSTR('|~*~|'||p.departments||'|~*~|'
        ,'|~*~|'||d.key||'|~*~|') > 0;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d292e/4

Comment: Thank you Jeffery, this will work perfectly! You've got to love trying to support poorly designed vendor applications!

Comment: Just realised last night that you could sort by the result of INSTR if you really need the names sorted in order of the ID list. Updated.

Comment: Good find. That may come in handy. Thanks again! Very helpful.